# MIPS: store address not aligned on word boundary

Tags: memory, assembly, store, mips

I'm trying to write a program which works out the the number of non space characters, characters and words in a sentence using MIPS assembly language. I have succeeded in doing this but I have little issue right at the end.

I have got the values of these things like number of spaces in random registers and am trying to save them into 3 registers next to one another ($s1, $s2, $s3) but when I run my program (using Mars) I get the following error: Runtime exception at 0x00400070: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x0000001e

I will post my code below. Thanks in advance for any any answers!

```
    .data 

char_count: .word 0 

space_count: .word 0 

word_count: .word 0 

text_input: .asciiz "I'm having an old friend for dinner." 

    .text  
    .globl main

main:
la $s0, char_count        #t1 storing char_count address         

la $t0, text_input # Loading the text
li $t1, 0 # Making the character counter 0
addi $t5, $t5, 0x20 # Loading up the hex value for space
addi $t8, $t8, 0 # Making the register which decides whether or not the characters     (spaces/letters) before the space were a word.
addi $t9, $t9, 1 # Used for comparing the $t8 register to
addi $s4, $s4, 0 # Used for camping the $t8 register to

count:  
lb $t2, 0($t0)  # Load the first byte from address in $t0  
beqz $t2, end   # If the byte is 0 then jump to the end of the program
beq $t2, $t5, space # If the byte is a space then jump to the part of the program which     adds one to the space counter
beq $t8, $t9, continue   # If the word deciding register equals 1 then skip to the         continue part (to stop $t8 getting bigger than 1).
addi $t8, $t8, 1 # Add 1 to the register to indicate that a letter was the last byte.
continue:
add $t1, $t1, 1 # Increment the counter
add $t0, $t0, 1      # Increment the address  
j count      # This then loops this part of the program  

space:
addi $t4, $t4, 1 # Add 1 to the space counter
beq $t8, $s4, continue # If word deciding register equals 0 then jump to continue
sub $t8, $t8, $t9 # Make word deciding register ($t8) go back to 0
addi $t3, $t3, 1 # Add 1 to word counter
jal continue    

end:
beq $t8, $s4, finish
addi $t3, $t3, 1 # If last byte in the string was a character than another word must be         added. This stops spaces at the end being counted as a word.

finish:

sub $t6, $t1,$t4 # This works out the number of non space characters by doing number of     characters minus spaces.

sw $s1, ($t6)           # Trying to store number of non spaces in s1
sw $s2, ($t4)            #  Trying to store number of spaces in s2
sw $s3, ($t3)            # trying to store number of words in s3

li $v0, 10
syscall # Terminates the program.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using `sw` doesn't match what you seem to be trying to do:

```
sw $s1, ($t6)           # Trying to store number of non spaces in s1
```

What that line actually does it store the word contained in `$s1` at the location in memory pointed to by `$t6`.

If you just wanted to copy the contents of `$t6` into `$s1` you should use:

```
move $s1, $t6
```

And if you wanted to store `$t6` in memory at the location pointed to by `$s1` you should use:

```
sw $t6, ($s1)
```

Keep in mind that in this case you need to place a valid address in `$s1` first; e.g. `la $s1, char_count`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I'm trying to do is store $t6 in the memory at location $t1. I put the la $s1, char_count in the main but it still doesn't work. Am I doing this right? Also, for the three different stores would I need to place 3 valid addresses?

Comment: Ok, I tried your suggestions again and now it runs without any errors. However, I don't see the value that is in $t6 in $s1. Should I be seeing the value in $s1, or am I confused about the meaning of the sw function?

Comment: What do you mean by "in `$s1`"? Are you talking about the value of `$s1` or the value in memory pointed to by `$s1`?  `sw` is used to store the values of registers to memory, not to move values from one register to another.

Comment: I want to store the value in s1. Say t6 displayed 5 I would like s1 to also say 5. Do I need to use the move function for this or will sw work? Thanks

Comment: You should use `move` for that.